# How to release temporarily consumed GPU memory after each forward?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, gpu, pytorch

I have a class like this:

```
class Stem(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Stem, self).__init__()
        self.out_1 = BasicConv2D(3, 32, kernelSize = 3, stride = 2)
        self.out_2 = BasicConv2D(32, 32, kernelSize = 3, stride = 1)
        self.out_3 = BasicConv2D(32, 64, kernelSize = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.out_1(x)
        x = self.out_2(x)
        x = self.out_3(x)

        return x
```

and the attributes `out_1,2,3` of `Stem` are instances of below class:

```
class BasicConv2D(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize, stride, padding = 0):
        super(BasicConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(inChannels, outChannels,
                            kernel_size = kernelSize,
                            stride = stride,
                            padding = padding, bias = False)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(outChannels,
                                    eps = 0.001,
                                    momentum = 0.1,
                                    affine = True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace = False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        y = self.relu(x)
        return y
```

when training, within `Stem.forward()`, `nvidia-smi` tells that each line will consume `x` MBs GPU memory, but after `Stem.forward()` finished, the memory won't be released, causing the training to quickly crashed, out of GPU memory.

The question is thus:
how to release the temporarily consumed GPU memory?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your pytorch model. Did you check for any leaks in the batch generation maybe, or in the way you may be storing results, etc.?

Comment: I agree with @ Aldream the problem lies probably somewhere in the rest of your code. So you might post for example the code within the training loop instead. Or check your generation step like @Aldream suggested.

Comment: @Aldream,I think it is due to pytorch,by default,will keep compute graph before backward,so question is how to clear clear compute graph before backward

Comment: You can't clear the compute graph before backward because you need it for the backward. You can try to use checkpointing to reduce the memory consumption https://pytorch.org/docs/master/checkpoint.html?highlight=checkpoint#torch-utils-checkpoint

Answer (score 1):

Your model does look good, so you might want to have a general look at how pytorch manages memory allocation. I suspect that you simply keep pointers to your return value (y) alive (e.g. by accumulating a loss or some such). As pytorch stores the entire attached computation graph, you never free the memory.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47587122/4385912) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600843/4385912) for a more detailed discussion.